# Alternative to this prompt

Tags: paraphrasing

In a hotel, they write below lines to prompt customers to remove the plates and place that to dustbin after done with eating.

> After eating remove the plate

I am so curious about knowing any alternate sentences without leading to open up a dictionary to understand it.

Comment: +1 for *...without leading to open up a dictionary to understand it!!!*

Comment: While remove seems opt word, it doesn't sound polite and respectful

Comment: but they already said *please*

Comment: Oops,, sorry i once again looked over the statement, and there's no `please` in the board!So i edit the question[as please missed, i raised question here, but i myself added it while typing, ha ha]

Comment: there you got it. *After eating, **please** remove the plates.* - You answered yourself!

Comment: Hmmmm! I will be happy more on any alternative sentence! But thanks a lot Maulik

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it, and I am not sure opening a dictionary would help. Remove the plates from where? Where is dustbin mentioned in the instruction? Why would you throw plates into the dustbin?

Comment: Yeah!  That's why this question raised!  The statement doesn't convey much details

Comment: What kind of alternatives do you want? Is your problem with the use of the word "remove" here?

Comment: I expect any phrase that best describes this scene

Comment: I still don't get the scene. Do you know what the instruction was *intended* to convey? To put it in a somewhat more informal way, what exactly does the restaurant wish its customers would do?

Comment: @Happy, the restaurant wants to convey that they'll serve customers till they're done eating; Next is (disposal of plates to cleaning desk) individual's responsibility.

Comment: I see, I get it now. It is some sort of a "semi buffet", where the restaurant employee serves you food, but you are expected to return the dishes when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

The following instruction would serve the purpose well.

> Please return your plates to the cleaning desk before you leave.

IMHO, it explains clearly enough what the customers are expected to do with their plates, without sounding rude or childish.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the customers have to remove their plates after eating, I think the restaurant does not **serve** its clients. That's because I guess removing the plates **does** come under their service. And, if this is the case, I'd use a simple message that conveys everything - **Self-service.**

> [self service](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/self-service) -  A self-service restaurant or shop is one in which you serve yourself and are **not served by the people who work there.**

I'm not sure of a restaurant wherein a waiter takes order, gets you your dish but at the time of removing the plates, disappears!

Comment: Consider this restaurant as of the kind!  The management does maintain some supremacy to his employees!

Comment: @nmxprime so here, they get you your plates on the table but don't remove them?

Comment: Yes! It's not issue they not removing it, but the statement doesn't sound better